# Edit to require SSL in IIS6 cause app pool recycle?

Tags: ssl, iis-6, application-pool

If I have a running website and I edit the secure communications to always require SSL...will it recycle the app pool?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article... http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/08/02/asp-net-case-study-lost-session-variables-and-appdomain-recycles.aspx. Based on this I'd say yes, as most config changes cause a recycle.